# Eclipse crash and cannot open

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was running an application for a long time while suddenly eclipse crash and until now cannot open. I am using Win 7 O.S and java 7. I have never set the `HOME` variable while Eclipse was working perfectly. After Eclipse crashed i set up the `HOME_JAVA` but the problem is the same.I cannot open eclipse from the workbench.

My Metadata file has the below lines.

```
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2014-06-03 10:39:07.782
!MESSAGE Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (629).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.instantiateBuilder(BuildManager.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.initializeBuilder(BuildManager.java:859)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.getBuilder(BuildManager.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.getBuilder(BuildManager.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin.start() of bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getResources(JFaceResources.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageRegistry.<init>(ImageRegistry.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageRegistry.<init>(ImageRegistry.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchImages.initializeImageRegistry(WorkbenchImages.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchImages.getDescriptors(WorkbenchImages.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchImages.getImageDescriptor(WorkbenchImages.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SharedImages.getImageDescriptor(SharedImages.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(AbstractUIPlugin.java:671)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin.startEditors(AdtPlugin.java:1528)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin.start(AdtPlugin.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 34 more
```

Can anyone help me how to solve that issue??

Comment: an plugin cause this problem, try to delete the plugin in your file explorer (folder:  eclipse->plugins)

Comment: try this Go to yourWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins and delete everything in there. Eclipse will start and repopulate the folder.

Comment: It's not HOME_JAVA, it's JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I delete everything from .metadata/.plugins and works again.

Comment: @Duggu A warning - deleting .metadata/.plugins removes all imported git/gradle projects, and resets the workbench layout

Comment: As the first line of the stack shows, the "subentry" is "org.eclipse.equinox.registry". Find it in eclipse->plugins folder and remove it, then you can restart. You do not need delete all of them.

Comment: @duggu Don't you want to post it as answer? :)

Answer (score 15):

There is **no need** to remove the entire `your-workspace/.metadata/.plugins` directory.

Just remove the file `your-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`.

This stores the list of files opened in the workbench, one of them (very likely a `pom.xml`) is causing the problem you're experiencing.